# Matrix Factorization in Recommender Systems: Multiple solutions?

Tags: svd, recommender-system

I have implemented a recommender system for predicting user ratings based on the matrix factorization approach.

$$
r_{ui}=μ+b_u+b_i+q_i^T p_u
$$

Where **q** and **p** are found by mimization of the squared error function with regularization of the rated itens
$$
(p^*,q^* ) = \text{argmin} \sum (r_{ui}- q_i^T p_u)^2+λ(q_i^2+p_u^2)
$$

Problem is that I’m getting slightly different predictions each time.

I suppose this a  local optima problem since the objective function is not convex. Yet I haven’t seen any discussions on this issue on my research.

Increasing the value of the regularization parameters mitigates the problem in the simulation but the optimal value changes with the size of the utility matrix, and in real life application I won't really know in advance the size of the matrices.  Recalibrating  the “lambdas” in each situation would be extremely inconvenient.

Any clues on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is a well-known [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization#Uniqueness) in the context of Matrix Factorization based methods: solutions are not unique.

Indeed, let's consider a non-singular matrix $U$. Let's introduce new vectors

$$
q'_i = U^T q_i \quad \quad
p'_u = U^{-1} p_u
$$

It's easy to see that inner product of new vectors is the same as inner product of old ones, since $U$ and $U^{-1}$ cancel each other out when multiplied. Moreover, if $U$ is [unitary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix), then it's known to be norm-preserving, which means that L2 regularization term will stay the same.

That said, I'm not familiar with approaches to solve this problem. According to the Wikipedia, in order to fix the issue one should use sparsity constraints. There are several papers on the subject, though all of them deal with non-negative factorization:

- [Sparse and Unique Nonnegative Matrix Factorization Through Data
  Preprocessing](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2436)
- [Sparse Coding and NMF](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~mnl/store/EggertKorner2004a.pdf)
- [First results on uniqueness of sparse non-negative matrix factorization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.378.8703&rep=rep1&type=pdf)